# Setting up keystore for Spark authentication

Tags: java, apache-spark, ssl, keystore, keytool

I have a Self signed certificate with keystore password set up in the product. I'm trying to re-use this keystore for spark authentication by importing it and changing the spark-defaults.conf accordingly on spark restarts.  Purpose is to have the keystore password change on every restart and hence the spark web UI password.

Here is the Java keytool command I'm using to achieve this:

> keytool -importkeystore -noprompt -destalias sparkCert -destkeystore
>   dest.keystore -deststorepass  -srckeystore src.keystore
>   -srcstoretype JKS -srcstorepass  -srcalias selfsignedcertificate -destkeypass  -deststoretype JKS -J-Duser.language=en

After successfully executing this, I add the following lines to spark-defaults.conf:

```
spark.authenticate=true

spark.ui.enabled=true

spark.master.rest.enabled=false

spark.ui.filters=com.xyz.BasicAuthFilter

spark.ssl.enabled=true 

spark.ui.https.enabled=true 

spark.ssl.keyPassword=spark.secret spark.ssl.keyStore=<path to    dest.keystore> 

spark.ssl.keyStorePassword=<random-string set as password above>    

spark.ssl.protocol=TLS
```

Above two steps are done before spark startup call. Issue I'm facing is, the new password provided above doesn't work to login to https://spark-master-name:8480

It works if I use the source keystore password.

What is it that is still holding spark and the  old keystore password tied together? At the keystore level, the new password seems to be applied just fine (I'm able to use the new password to query the keystore). But I cannot authenticate spark with it. Any pointers are appreciated. I'm new to Spark technology, not very well-versed with SSL either.